# mean! may return incorrect results

Tags: statistics, julia

I recently had the following question
regarding the function `mean!` of the `Statistics.jl` package.

The following bug is reported regarding the behavior of `mean!`. As indicated, the `mean!` function does not properly consider that its arguments may alias each other. In some such cases the result from `mean!` is not correct:

```
julia> let a = [1 2 3]
       mean!(a, a)
   end
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
0  0  0

julia> let a = [1 2 3]
       mean!(copy(a), a)
   end
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
1  2  3

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.5.3
Commit 788b2c77c1 (2020-11-09 13:37 UTC)
Platform Info:
 OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)
 CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
 WORD_SIZE: 64
 LIBM: libopenlibm
 LLVM: libLLVM-9.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

However, I think that this behavior is normal since viewing the definition of `mean!`, the result of the operation `mean!(r, v)` is written in `r`. Therefore it seems logical to me that if you use the same object as variable `r` and as variable `v`, the result is unpredictable.

I have seen that this also happens with the `sum!` function.

Someone can tell me if I am right or indeed, there is something that I am not understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mean!` behaves the way you observe because it internally calls `sum!`.

Now `sum!` behaves this way for the following reason. It was designed to perform summation without making any allocations. Therefore the first thing `sum!` does is initializing the target vector to `0` (a neutral element of summation). After this is done your `a` vector contains only `0`s, and thus later you get all `0`s also.

However, indeed it would make sense that the `sum!` (and similar) functions docstring should mention that the target should not alias with the source. Here is another example of the same you have observed:

```
julia> x = [1 2 3
            4 5 6
            7 8 9]
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9

julia> y = view(x, :, 1)
3-element view(::Matrix{Int64}, :, 1) with eltype Int64:
 1
 4
 7

julia> sum!(y, x)
3-element view(::Matrix{Int64}, :, 1) with eltype Int64:
  5
 11
 17

julia> x
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
  5  2  3
 11  5  6
 17  8  9
```

Comment: xref https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/39385

Comment: xref https://github.com/JuliaLang/Statistics.jl/issues/71